# OrientDB is a graph database?

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to understand how OrientDB can be a graph and a document database at the same time.

How a document is persisted? It appears to be different compared with ArangoDB, when everything is a document.

OrientDB is a graph database that supports documents? The documents are graph nodes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Orientdb graphs work on top of the documents.
http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Choosing-between-Graph-or-Document-API.html

(So one would say orientdb is a document db which supports graphs.)

Therefore documents are much faster when accessing.

With graphs you can have edges (bi directional) while in documents you only have links.